# Using Convoluted layers in Neural Networks

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to use a Conv1D layer an input layer in my neural network on Keras which I understand is a temporal convolution layer. What I understand is that it takes the input, and uses a kernel size (with a set no of features) to create a new convoluted layer. My training data is a long one hot encoded tensor of length 231. I am struggling to understand how/what the input of a Conv1D layer is?

My `x_train.shape([1])` is 231.

When I use:

```
n_cols = x_train.shape([1])

model.add(Conv1D(128, 11, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (n_cols,)))
```

(I use 11 because from my understanding I believe it takes 11 values from my one hot vector at one time)

I receive the error message:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 231]
```

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Hajar's     HDD/MSc_data/large_proteins/ml_network.py", line 18, in <module>
        model.add(Conv1D(128, 11, activation = 'relu', input_shape     = (n_cols,)))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 456, in     _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 169, in     add
    layer(x)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 589, in     __call__
    self.name)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 124, in     assert_input_compatibility
    str(x.shape.as_list()))
```

I've attempted to change the kernel​ size but I still get the same error. I think maybe I need another input layer before. For kernal size, is this the number of features ie 231?

Comment: As per Keras documentation - `When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide an input_shape argument (tuple of integers or None, does not include the batch axis), e.g. input_shape=(10, 128) for time series sequences of 10 time steps with 128 features per step in data_format="channels_last", or (None, 128) for variable-length sequences with 128 features per step.`

Comment: I have read this already. I'm struggling to understand what it means exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will require an input of `shape=(231, x )` where x is the 2nd dimension. You can try using `x = 1` like :

```
import numpy as np

n_cols = x_train.shape([1])
x_train = np.reshape( x_train , ( -1 , n_cols , 1 )  )

model.add(Conv1D(128, 11, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (n_cols,1)))
```

`Conv1D` requires two-dimensional inputs in the form `(batch_size, a, b )` where `a` and `b` are non-zero dimensions.

Comment: I used the above and received the error message: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (45902, 231)`

Comment: I changed the input shape ( n_cols , 1 )

Comment: Try `input_shape = (None,231,1)`

Comment: I've tried both and still get an error: `ValueError: A target array with shape (1122818, 8) was passed for an output of shape (None, 221, 8) while using as loss 'categorical_crossentropy'. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.`

Comment: I believe the above error is because y_train needs to also be reshaped?